# Why does static IP work with NAT but not bridged adapter?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, virtualbox, ip

I have been attempting to create a static IP on my VirtualBox guest server running Debian 9 for some time now. After much troubleshooting I decided to attempt the same format in my `/etc/networking/interfaces` file with a NAT network adapter instead of bridged:

```
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
    address 10.0.2.99
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.2.2
```

And lo and behold after switching to NAT adapter it worked. Would someone be able to enlighten me as to why the static IP works with NAT but not bridged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a Bridged Adapter in VirtualBox, it connects the virtual NIC to one of your physical NICs, and it connects to the same network.

Either use DHCP (if you have DHCP service on your LAN) or use an available IP on the same subnet as your host machine.

Comment: Thank you. So why does this mean the same IP works when I am connecting to my host network through NAT, but when I attempt to use the same static IP with a bridged adapter, pings return `destination host unreachable`?

Comment: Because your host network is most likely not the 10.0.2.0/24 subnet .... you can test it.  Set to bridge mode, and run `dhclient -v enp0s3` and see what IP, netmask, gateway, etc. it gets.

Comment: ... or just look to see what the host is (already, successfully) using on this LAN.